# How can I tell when Foundry has updated Spark?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

There are very useful Spark features that are not yet available in the Spark version provided automatically by Foundry.

Spark upgrades don't seem to be announced on the [Foundry Releases page](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/release-notes/).

There doesn't seem to be a way to view information about the latest Foundry libraries e.g. `transforms`, and see what the pyspark dependency is.

The only way to find out seems to be trying to upgrade a repo:

- Use the Code Repositories Upgrade function to generate a Pull Request
- Check the pyspark version in `transforms-python/conda-versions.run.linux-64.lock`.

Which has the side-effect of creating a meaningless Pull Request, so isn't a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a dummy PR, you could create a new repo and check `conda-versions.run.linux-64.lock`. Then delete that repo.

This isn't much better answer than what you already do, but at least this lets you avoid the extra PR.